# install rgdal in windows

Tags: r, package

I want to read hdf4(MODIS) files in R using rgdal package, so I downloaded the additional hdf4 drivers by OSGeo4W, and then tried to install rgdal using source. The result is shown below:

```
install.packages("rgdal",type = "source")
```

> Installing package into ‘C:/Users/dell/Documents/R/win-library/3.3’
>   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified) trying URL
>   'https://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/CRAN/src/contrib/rgdal_1.2-5.tar.gz'
>   Content type 'application/gzip' length 1652472 bytes (1.6 MB)
>   downloaded 1.6 MB
>
> - installing *source* package 'rgdal' ...
>     ** package 'rgdal' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127 ERROR:
>     configuration failed for package 'rgdal'
> - removing 'C:/Users/dell/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rgdal' Warning in install.packages : running command
>     '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.3/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l
>     "C:\Users\dell\Documents\R\win-library\3.3"
>     C:\Users\dell\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmpywb4tp/downloaded_packages/rgdal_1.2-5.tar.gz'
>     had status 1 Warning in install.packages :   installation of package
>     ‘rgdal’ had non-zero exit status

Is this method wrong, or missing some crucial steps? I use R in Windows 10.